# VBA MS Access 2010 pivot line chart add data label to first marker only

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, pivot-chart

These little VBA language differences between Excel and Access are getting very anoying.  I am at the last step (hopefully) of getting my line chart to look how I need it to, but I can't get a data label to show on the first marker only.  Here is what I have so far.  I have attempted every itiration I can find online and all get the same "Error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method"

```
With Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0)
    .Line.Color = sc1
    .Line.Weight = 6
    .marker.Size = 8
    .marker.Style = 2
    sName = .Name
    csName = Right(sName, Len(sName) - 8)
    .Caption = csName
    .Points(1).DataLabel.Text = csName
End With
```

Again, thanks for your assistance.

Comment: The specific issue is the `.DataLabel`.  For some reason Access does not want to accept it after the `.points()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.. please insert these line before With Statement

```
Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0).SeriesCollection(0).Points(1).DataLabel.Select
Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Name"
```

if issue still persist then try to change `Me.ChartSpace.Charts(0)` to  `Sheets("SheetName").ChartObjects("ChartName")` and put the appropriate `SeriesCollection` number

Comment: Thanks, but unforunetly, this is in Access, not Excel.